# Composite primary key and junction table constraints violated

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

myTable    `id,  admitDate, dischargeDate` PK
jxn        `id ,code`
codetable  `code, description`

There are many other fields in myTable and the only way to have a unique identifier for each record is to have the three value PK of id, admitDate, dischargeDate.  If the same person (same ID) was admitted twice, then the ID will be repeated, but the admitDate and dischargeDates will be different.  I tried to copy the `id` portion of the primary key from myTable to the jxn table and SSMS got mad and said I don't have a unique constraint.

I realize that this won't work now, but I was wondering how in practice would this problem by typically solved?  As I said, the only way to identify a record reliably is by those three fields together.  How do I deal with the people with more than one admission/discharge?

Will I need to find the people who violate the unique constraints of the PK and move them into a `moreThanOneAdmission` table?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get away with a composite primary key of the patient ID and the admission date (possibly plus time).  You may not know the discharge date if they haven't been discharged yet.

If you got an error about your unique constraint, it is probably because you had an error in how it was defined.  It is definitely legal to have a composite primary key.

To join do a full inner join of the patient admissions table with a junction table then the FK in the junction table must have a foreign key consisting of (all three of) the PK fields from the patient admissions table.

Comment: This is a retrospective database, so I'll never have to worry about if someone has been discharged yet.  My problem is that patient 1234 was admitted and discharged on, say 4/23/2009.  Patient 1234 was then admitted and discharged on 5/21/2009.  So although the CPK works fine, when I try to join it with another, already-created junction table, it fails.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - What is the structure of the junction table you're trying to join?  If it is a child of your patient admissions table then the FK in the junction table should have all three of your PK fields to make the FK.

Comment: the junction table only included a copy of the patientID.  I thought that it might work if I only copied the patientID part.. but your suggestion was even better because it made me think of something else. if you submit a formal answer i'll accept it :)